# Problems after updating Manjaro Xfce - laptop turned off. How to fix?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro

I was updating Manjaro Xfce and the laptop turned off in the middle of the update, and when I tried to turn it on it had a problem with grub, I already solved this but there are some apps that do not start, for example telegram, and now when I install something new it always shows me this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Given the laptop shutdown, are you able to completely reinstall xfce?  I have reinstalled xfce in Kali.

Comment: Hello, please remember that you should ask **questions** here. There wasn't one, I added the most obvious "How to fix?", but you could make it more detailed. This is also an English website, so translate the error to English from Spanish.

Comment: Hey @QuinteroDevy Please ask a question and avoid screenshots.... Anyway ... `pacman -Qkk` might help ...